# Fan out in B+ trees

Tags: algorithm, b-tree

How does fan out exactly affects split and merge in B+ trees?

If I have 1024 Bytes page and 8 byte key, and maybe 8 byte pointer, i can store around 64 keys in one page. Considering one page will be my node, so if i have a fan out of 80%, does it mean the split will happen after the node is 80% full like after 52 keys are inserted or only after the node overflows.

Same for merge, when do we merge the nodes if we have like 80% fan out, when the keys go less than half the size of node or 80% has something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Splits and merges in B-trees of all kinds are usually driven by policies based on fullness criteria. It is best to think about fullness in terms of node space utilisation instead of key counts; fixed-size structures - where space utilisation is measured in terms of key counts and is thus equivalent to fanout - tend to occur only in academia and special contexts like in-memory B-trees on integers or hashes. In practice there are usually variable-size elements involved, beginning with variable-size keys that are subject to further size variation via things like prefix/suffix truncation and compression.

Splits almost invariably occur only when an update operation would result in an overflowed node. The difference between policies lies in how hard they try to shift keys to neighbouring nodes in order to avoid a split (looking at only one sibling or at both) and in how many keys they try to offload (one or several). Some locking strategies require preventive splitting/merging during initial descent, to guarantee that no splits or merges can occur on the way back up. In that case the decision must be made based on minimum/maximum possible key sizes instead of looking at the sizes of actual keys.

Some strategies only split when they have two full neighbouring nodes which they then split into three nodes, and they merge only if they have three neighbouring nodes that are on the verge of underflow (resulting in two full nodes). The net result is a high minimum utilisation of 2/3, with an average utilisation of 3/4 or higher. However, the increased complexity of the update algorithms is rarely worth the candle.

On the whole, the criteria can be summarised thus: split when a node threatens to overflow and offloading of keys to neighbours is not possible, merge when a node threatens to underflow and none of the neighbours can donate a key.